# how to save and send NSMutableAttributedString (Obtained by using coreText) to server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-text

```
Hi all,
```

I am trying to bold the selected text of `UITextView`.For that i am using coreText approach.In this i am able to bold the selected text and display on context using `NSMutableAtrributedString`.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

 NSLog(@"return str.....%@",[PISTrialViewController returnString]);
 NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
           initWithString:[PISTrialViewController returnString]];
 NSLog(@"attrrrr.....%@",string);
 tempRange=[PISTrialViewController returnRange];
 // make a few words bold
 CTFontRef helvetica = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica"), 14.0, NULL);
 CTFontRef helveticaBold = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica-Bold"), 14.0, NULL);


 NSLog(@"location.....%d",tempRange.location);
 NSLog(@"length.....%d",tempRange.length);
 [string addAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName
       value:(id)helveticaBold
       range:NSMakeRange(tempRange.location,tempRange.length)];

  // layout master
 CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(
                     (CFAttributedStringRef)string);

 // left column form
 CGMutablePathRef leftColumnPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
 CGPathAddRect(leftColumnPath, NULL, 
      CGRectMake(0, 0, 
        self.bounds.size.width,
        self.bounds.size.height));

 // left column frame
 CTFrameRef leftFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, 
             CFRangeMake(0, 0),
             leftColumnPath, NULL);


  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
 CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
 CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
 CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);


 // draw
 CTFrameDraw(leftFrame, context);

 // cleanup
 CFRelease(leftFrame);
 CGPathRelease(leftColumnPath);

 CFRelease(framesetter);
 CFRelease(helvetica);
 CFRelease(helveticaBold);
 [string release];
}
```

I have selected some text from UITextView and send that text to subclass of UIView where i have written this method(drawRect).The context drawn in uiview displays the selected text as bold.But now i am unable to select the text further.How can i do that?

How to save/retrieve `NSMutableAtrributedString` in/from sqlite database?

How can i send it on server?(in which format?)

Comment: Hi.. did you get any solution for this? I want to store the nsmutablestring into server side. i.e through API coded in PHP

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableAtrributedString implements the NSCoding protocol, so you can use NSKeyedArchiver to serialize them.